# Getting error in curl command which send the content of the file as text in the POST

Tags: curl

I have a xml file in the same folder where curl.exe is there when i am running below command from command line i am getting below error
Note the character ‘<’ preceding the name of the XML file. It instructs curl to send the content of the file as text in the POST and not as a file.

curl –F “xmlfile=<101.xml” –F “status=xyz” http://MyServer:8080/someservlet

The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Works fine for me. I have curl set up on the PATH, so I don't need to be in the curl.exe directory. But in working directory `C:/temp>` that I ran the command from, that's where the file is. Not sure why It's not working for you.

Comment: I am still getting the error don't know why

Comment: I used the exact same command you are, except for the url, so I am not sure why :-(

Comment: Can you please tell what is the command you have used

Comment: `C:\temp>curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/file -F "xmlFile=<hello.xml" -F "status=xyz"`